# Attribute Error in class attribute

Tags: python, class

I have written a class called `cl`:

```
class cl :
def __int__(self):
    self.a = 0


def increment(self):
    self.a +=1

def print_a(self):
    print ("value : "+str(self.a))
```

I have written another class called `test`. However, I got an error when calling methods.

```
 from cl import *

class test :
    def __int__(self):
        self.b = 0
        self.c = cl()


def main(self):
    self.c.increment()
    self.c.print_a()
    self.c.increment()
    self.c.print_a()

d = test()
d.main()
```

What I got is this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_file.py", line 19, in <module>

    d.main()
  File "test_file.py", line 12, in main
    self.c.increment()
AttributeError: test instance has no attribute 'c'
```

Can anyone explain why that happens and what is the issue with my code? I am a high school student. Can you explain to me? And can you help me to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misspelling `__init__` with `__int__`:

```
class cl :
    def __int__(self):
        self.a = 0
```

Should be

```
class cl :
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
```

Note that encompassing a main method inside of the `test` class is really an anti-pattern in Python; the form of

```
def main():
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

is preferred and is more Pythonic.

For some reference on the `if __name__ == "__main__"` pattern, see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/1730261
- [https://docs.python.org/3/library/**main**.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind help, can you little bit explain the mechanism or can you give me a link to refer ?

Answer (score 1):

main function does not belong the class test , it belongs the test.py which your test class in, so the self in main is test.py , not test